# MVVMCross - Bind the same ViewModel to 2 different Views

Tags: mvvm, mvvmcross

Basically my scenario is the following: I have 1 View bound to a ViewModel, with a List of items(the items' class is a class in my Model). Every time an item is selected from the list in this 'List View', its fields are edited in another, 'Details View'. This is identical to the Customer Management sample scenario, where a customer is selected from the List (in a 'List View') and the the Customer's details can be changed in a 'Details View'. **The added quirk in my scenario, is that I want the changes done to the item in the Details View, to be reflected back in the List View.** The changes are saved in DB from the Details View.

Also, depending on the changes done in the Details View, the item can be removed from list in the first View. Note that this is not deleting the record from the DB, because the list in the List View is just a *filtered* list of the items in the DB. I figured out two possible ways that I can do this:

1. By binding the 2 Views to the same View Model

**EDIT**: **How do I call the second view? Will the second view actually use the same instance of the shared ViewModel?**

-or-
 2. By passing the item selected in the List View ***by reference*** to the Details View. Therefore in this case, I'm maintaining the **1-View-to-1-ViewModel mapping**.

My questions are:

- how can I implement scenario 1,
- in 2, does the `Init()` method(used in conjunction with the `ShowViewModel()` method) **support passing parameters by
  reference**?

I would be grateful, if you could include code snippets/examples in your answers.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: @Stuart: Hi Stuart, sorry to come back after a week on this; just edit my original post and added an additional question/clarification on "binding 2 Views to the same View Model" topic, that I forgot to put originally:How do I call the second view?. Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> binding 2 Views to the same View Model

You are free to set the `ViewModel` property on any `View` manually if you wish to. Simply set `ViewModel = foo;` before the call to `base.OnCreate()`, `base.OnNavigatedTo()` or `base.ViewDidLoad()`

> in 2, does the Init() method(used in conjunction with the ShowViewModel() method) support passing parameters by reference?

MvvmCross does not support passing objects between ViewModels. On Windows Phone navigations are performed by url parameters. On Android, navigations are performed by `Intent`s - these underlying mechanisms simply do not let you pass actual object references.

---

In general I handle this situation using messaging from the data store to the ViewModel

> I would be grateful, if you could include code snippets/examples in your answers.

You can see how I typically do this in N=12 to N=15 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/

Comment: Thanx Stuart. I'll try/check out all the suggestions.