# Bind Two Different Views for same ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding, binding, mvvmcross

This looks like similar to [MVVMCross - Bind the same ViewModel to 2 different Views](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20174483/3108449)

But after there I don't get an answer how can I select one View for ViewModel and in another time the second View for the same ViewModel.

As an example, I wanna have one ViewModel - `LoginViewModel` and two Views: `PhoneLoginPage` & `TabletLoginPage`.

According to information from `Xamarin.Forms.Device.Idiom` when it's a Phone I want to show `PhoneLoginPage` but when it's a Tablet - `TabletLoginPage` but have the same `LoginViewModel` binded to them.

How can I achieve it correctly? Mean, without any dirty tricks...

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like one page could suit you.

Comment: I will have folder Phones and Tables and for each page two different files for all app, because UI is really different for 80% of pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MvvmCross this is not possible, in runtime, we will get an Exception if we create two Views for the same ViewModel.

My solution was next:

```
<ProjectFolder>
    => Pages
        => Mobile
            XMobilePage.xaml
            YMobilePage.xaml
        => Tablets
            XTabletPage.xaml
            YTabletPage.xaml
    => PageModels
        => Mobile
            XMobilePageModel.cs
            YMobilePageModel.cs
        => Tablets
            XTabletPageModel.cs
            YTabletPageModel.cs
```

```cs
class XMobilePage: MvxContentPage<XMobilePageModel> {...}

class XTabletPage: MvxContentPage<XTabletPageModel> {...}

abstract SharedXPageModel
{
    //All Shared Commands and Comand Logic and other shared initialization
    abstract Task NavigateToYPageModel();
}

class XMobilePageModel : SharedXPageModel
{
    Task NavigateToYPageModel() => _mvxNavigationService.Navigate<YMobilePageModel>();
}

class XTabletPageModel : SharedXPageModel
{
    Task NavigateToYPageModel() => _mvxNavigationService.Navigate<YTabletPageModel>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*NOTE: I'm also on the side of having only one page.*

But here's how I'd go about having two pages:

#### In case you're using some kind of a navigation service:

Just register different pages on app startup based on the device's idiom.

Along the lines of:

```cs
if(Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
{
    SomeNavigationService.Register<LoginViewModel, TabletLoginPage>();
}
else
{
    SomeNavigationService.Register<LoginViewModel, PhoneLoginPage>();
}
```

#### In case you're doing the navigation in the page code-behind

Choose the page based on the device's idiom there...

```cs
if(Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new TabletLoginPage(viewModel));
}
else
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new PhoneLoginPage(viewModel));
}
```

Comment: This is a really good approach but MvvmCross does not support it and it can't be done in that way there, unfortunately.....