# ViewModel data is being shared for each Page while Reusing single ViewModel for different Views

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm, viewmodel

This is somehow similar to the repeated questions like [Bind Two Different Views for same ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65771514/bind-two-different-views-for-same-viewmodel)
But I am on the AppShell to show pages and having issue related to data:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="News &amp; Updates" Icon="icon_feed.png" >
    <Tab x:Name="UriUpdates" Title="News &amp; Updates" >
        <ShellContent Title="News" Route="NewsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Notifications" Route="NotificationsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NotificationsPage}" />           
    </Tab>        
</FlyoutItem>
```

Both pages are using a custom control of type **ContentView**.
In the code-behind of the pages I have provided the BindingContext

```
BindingContext = _viewModel = new UpdatesViewModel("news");
BindingContext = _viewModel = new UpdatesViewModel("notifications");
```

ViewModel has a property UpdateType which is updated in constructor and its value is used in the command (ExecuteLoadItemsCommand) to fill out the list (Items):

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<UpdatesModel>();
LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());
```

The event ExecuteLoadItemsCommand() causes the VM to fill the Data from a DataStore

```
public IDataStore<UpdatesModel> DataStore => DependencyService.Get<IDataStore<UpdatesModel>>();
```

**ExecuteLoadItemsCommand** is called as expected and fills the respective items every time.

```
async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    try
    {
        Items.Clear();
        var items = await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(UpdateType);
        if(items!=null)
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

**GetItemsAsync** is in DataStore which returns the required items list:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UpdatesModel>> GetItemsAsync(string updateType, bool forceRefresh = false)
{
    if (forceRefresh || items == null || items.Count == 0)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(Constants.GetUpdatesUrl(updateType));
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                items = (List<UpdatesModel>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<UpdatesModel>>(content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }   
    return await Task.FromResult(items);
}
```

What I think is whenever items are filled for a page News/Notifications it must not call the Rest-Service again and again for each tab-change click. It should update the items when required.
So for this purpose I applied a condition in the method *GetItemsAsync* of *DataStore* (which is implementation of *IDataStore*) as

```
if (forceRefresh || items == null || items.Count == 0)
{
    //Rest Service Call to fill items list
}
```

The problem is items (which is a property in VM) are always non-empty and filled with 1st page data (News items).
After **NewsPage** is loaded, I don't know why the items are not empty and are filled with *NewsPage* data when **NotificationsPage** is being loaded.

Kindly help me out whether I am having a bad practice to share VM for different views or there is some issue which is causing the pages to have data which is filled in items by 1st page?

Comment: UpdateType or UpdateModel ? cause I don't see a UpdateType  in your code. items  or Items ? I think you should include more code I don't think we can see the whole picture only from what you shared.

Comment: thanks for the reply. when BindingContext = _viewModel = new UpdatesViewModel("news"); is being called, the viewModel has a property UpdateType which is used to get respective data from rest service and as I have mentioned this UpdateType (news/notifications) is being used in **ExecuteLoadItemsCommand**

Comment: everything works fine when I allow Fill Items on every call of ExecuteLoadItemsCommand but when I force to fill items in a case when items are empty, the issue comes. For 1st Page Items are filled because it was empty, and for next Tab when same VM is used for 2nd Page, it shows items are not empty and 2nd Page also gets the same list of items which were filled with 1st Page

Comment: @Cfun it is possible to clear items at necessary points but the issue is Why Items are already filled for a 2nd Page having the same VM? while debugging when 1st Page  (NewsPage) is being loaded the Items are filled but when 2nd Page is being loaded the Items are not empty and have the data of previously filled items.

Comment: Items are being shown in a ContentView with 
```<CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="None">```

Comment: @M.Waseem It is difficult to reproduce your problem, so can you provide one simple sample to test?

Answer (score 0):

What was the mistake, I blamed the ViewModel for causing the Data to be shared on every page for Items List which is defined in VM :

`public ObservableCollection<UpdatesModel> Items { get; }`

But the data was being shared because of **[DependencyService :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/)**

`public IDataStore<UpdatesModel> DataStore => DependencyService.Get<IDataStore<UpdatesModel>>();`

so it has **shared code** which means it is a single instance and being shared to VM.

***I resolved it by introducing a Dictionary*** in DataStore (implementation of IDataStore for DependencyService) as

`private Dictionary<string, List<UpdatesModel>> itemsDict;`

Instead of

`private List<UpdatesModel> items;`

and changed GetItemsAsync (which returns the data from Rest Service):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UpdatesModel>> GetItemsAsync(string updateType, bool forceRefresh = false)
{
    if (itemsDict == null || itemsDict.Count == 0) itemsDict = new Dictionary<string, List<UpdatesModel>>();

    if (forceRefresh || itemsDict == null || itemsDict.Count == 0 || !itemsDict.ContainsKey(updateType))
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(Constants.GetUpdatesUrl(updateType, startDate));
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                itemsDict[updateType] = (List<UpdatesModel>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<UpdatesModel>>(content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return await Task.FromResult(itemsDict[updateType]);
}
```

so for all distinct updateTypes passed to **GetItemsAsync** from ViewModel, a dictionary value (`itemsDict[updateType]`) is being returned and I don't have to refill items again and again as Dictionary is being filled only once or when forced to refill for any updateType as Key.